# Hibernate and no-arg constructor

Tags: java, hibernate

As we can read [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-pojo-constructor) Hibenate requires no-arg constructor for all the `@Entity` classes. But isn't it true that java class has always implicit default constuctor, even if we don't declare one explicitly?

In my project I don't declare a no-arg constructor in my `@Entity` classes and eveything works fine. But on the other hand, I guess that Hibernate specification has been written carefully so maybe actually declaring explicitely default constructor may have some benefits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are **no special benefits** of defining the no-arg constructor explicitly for the Entity Classes (But remember that, Hibernate framework internally uses the no-arg constructor to populate entities through Java reflection API).

It is mandatory that the Hibernate Entity Bean Classes require no-arg constructors, which can be defined explicitly by the programmer (or auto. generated by Java).

One important point is that **when you are defining your own constructor**(s) for the class, you need to **provide the no-arg constructor by yourself** (because the compiler does not provide in this case).

Answer (score 8):

If you create other constructor, java will not create implicit constructor.

Answer (score 2):

In Hibernate, no-arg constructor is used to  loading database entities via Reflection(that is used to examine or modify application behaviour at runtime).

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of the default no arg constructor, **is not mandatory** even for `Hibernate`, because java automatically and implicitely manage it.

And the only case where you need to specify it is *when you declare another parametrized constructor*.

If you take a look at **[The No-Arg Constructor](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page596.html)**, you will see that:

> Every class has at least one constructor. There are two cases:
>
> 1. If you do not write a constructor for a class, Java generates one
>      for
>      you. This generated constructor is called a default constructor. It's
>      not visible in your code, but it's there just the same. If you could
>      see it, it would look like this (for the class Dog):
>       public Dog() { } Notice that this default constructor takes no arguments and has a body that does nothing.
> 2. If you do write a constructor for your class, Java does not generate
>      a
>      default constructor. This could be a problem if you have pre-existing
>      code that uses the default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't define any constructors, the compiler will generate the default one, as described in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default
>   constructor with no formal parameters and no throws clause is
>   implicitly declared.
>
> If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the
>   default constructor has an empty body. Otherwise, the default
>   constructor simply invokes the superclass constructor with no
>   arguments.

This means that you don't have to explicitly implement the no-arg constructor for a Hibernate entity as long as:

1. You don't have any other constructors in the entity class;
2. The extended superclass has a no-arg constructor without a `throws` clause for any checked exceptions.

Comment: + for the 2nd. Exception would be thrown, because while extending, the super() is called which ofc calls no-arg constructor

Answer (score 0):

Java class might have no implicit default constructor.
Suppose, you have such a class:

```
public class A {
    public A(String st) {}
}
```

Eventually the only constructor would be A(String st), not A(String st) and A().